# Getting the values of that specific row on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Been doing this for hours now, and i still haven't found the solution,but the logic is there,grrr, Its just that Im stuck in getting the `id` of the button being clicked, I know this question been asked already, as i have implemented using `event.target.id` and `$('input[type="button"]').attr('id')`, but this does not work on my code,

I have a table with `3 rows` `and 12 td's` , and the last td of each row is being hidden and Im checking the value of that hidden td if its 0 or 1, and then `appending` a new `td` saying its `pending for value 0` and `accepted for value 1` and I'm assigning `Id`'s dynamically as you can see from the script below.

**Script**

```
var lastTr = $('table tbody').find('tr');
$(lastTr).find('td:last').hide();
var a = 0;
$(lastTr).find('td:last').each(function(){
    var textVal = $(this).text();
    if(textVal == 0){
        $(this).after('<td class="center"><button id="'+a+'" type="button" class="btn-danger">Pending</button></td>'); 
    }else if(textVal == 1){
        $(this).after('<td class="center"><button id="'+a+'" type="button" class="btn-success" disabled="disabled">Accepted</button></td>'); 
    }

    });
```

After that, I wanted to get the `first, second, tenth and eleventh` text value of that certain row that has been click, and this is my code below,

**Script**

```
//get specific value 1,2,10,11
    var value1, value2, value10, value11; //global variables which i will be needing later
    $('input[type="button"]').on('click', function(){
        var idButtonClicked = $(this).attr('id'); <--- im stuck getting the ID of the button being clicked
        console.log(idButtonClicked);
        $(idButtonClicked).parent().parent().find('td').each(function(){
            value1 = $('td:eq(0)').text();
            value2 = $('td:eq(1)').text();
            value10 = $('td:eq(9)').text();
            value11 = $('td:eq(10)').text();
        });
        console.log('value 1 = '+ value1);
        console.log('value 2 = '+ value2);
        console.log('value 9 = '+ value10);
        console.log('value 10 = '+ value11);

    });
```

My [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2K6TQ/6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delegate the event and change your selector as your currently adding a `button` to the HTML DOM not an `input`:

https://api.jquery.com/on/

http://jsfiddle.net/2K6TQ/7/

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
        var idButtonClicked = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(idButtonClicked);
        $(this).parent().parent().find('td').each(function(){
            value1 = $('td:eq(0)').text();
            value2 = $('td:eq(1)').text();
            value10 = $('td:eq(9)').text();
            value11 = $('td:eq(10)').text();
        });
        console.log('value 1 = '+ value1);
            console.log('value 2 = '+ value2);
            console.log('value 9 = '+ value10);
            console.log('value 10 = '+ value11);

    });
```

Comment: thanx, i haven't even consider the whole document. I was focused on the damn buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function(){
```

try that:

```
$('body').on('click','input[type="button"]' function(){
```

Because that first statement pertains only to those inputs that already exist at the time of javascript funcion's execution. The latter pertains to all potential future inputs that you add dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the selector wrong, it's not "input[type=button]", but "button".  I think you want this instead:

```
$('button').on('click', function() { /*...*/ });
```

Bear in mind though that when you're dynamically creating elements you have two choices in terms of binding events:

1. Remember to bind events every time you create an element
2. Use event delegation, for example on the body.

The latter is pretty simple, you just move your selector to be the second argument of the on() method call:

```
$('body').on('click', 'button', function() { /*...*/ });
```

I'm not sure if that fixes everything for you, but it should be a start :)

Comment: the selector is correct, just a typo for that being an `input` and a button, but will put in mind what you said, thanx